# Сборка через makefile gstreamer плеера - C Linux

Tags: linux, c, bash, gcc, makefile

Есть проблема, под линуксом не работал раньше. Нашел пример плеера с использованием [gstreamer](https://github.com/felipec/gst-player). Клонировал репозиторий и поправил код для работы с Gstreamer-1.0, пытаюсь в директории выполнить make! Компиляция проходит, а вот линковщик начинает ругаться на отсутствие библиотек, хотя в системе они есть и находятся в папке /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

Ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собираю на виртуальной машине. Я установил пакеты gtk2.0, libgstreamer1.0-dev, libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev, 
Собственно сам Makefile

```
CC=gcc

EXTRA_WARNINGS=-Wall -W -Wformat-nonliteral -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith \
           -Wbad-function-cast -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
           -Wmissing-declarations -Winline -Wundef -Wnested-externs -Wcast- 
qual \
           -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -Wfloat-equal - 
pedantic -ansi -std=c99

GST_LIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0)
GST_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0)
binaries=gst-player-1.0

GTK_LIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0)
GTK_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0)

CFLAGS := -ggdb -Wall $(EXTRA_WARNINGS)
LDFLAGS := LDFLAGS := -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/gstreamer-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64- 
linux-gnu/gtk-2.0
$(binaries): gstplayer.o gst-backend.o gst-frontend.o
$(binaries): CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GST_CFLAGS)
$(binaries): LIBS := $(LIBS) $(GTK_LIBS) $(GST_LIBS)

all: $(binaries)

$(binaries):
   $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $^

%.o:: %.c
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

clean:

Что мне необходимо сделать, что бы собрать приложение из объектных файлов и запустить его?

Установленные пакеты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заработало вот с таким мейк файлом:

```
CC=gcc

EXTRA_WARNINGS=-Wall -W -Wformat-nonliteral -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith \
           -Wbad-function-cast -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
           -Wmissing-declarations -Winline -Wundef -Wnested-externs -Wcast- 
qual \
           -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -Wfloat-equal - 
pedantic -ansi -std=c99

GST_LIBS=`pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0` -lgstvideo-1.0
GST_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0`
GTK_LIBS=`pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
GTK_CFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`

CFLAGS=-ggdb $(EXTRA_WARNINGS)

BINS=gst-player_os

all: $(BINS)

-player_os: gstplayer.c gst-backend.c gst-frontend.c
    $(CC) $+ $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GTK_LIBS) $(GST_CFLAGS) $(GST_LIBS) - 
   o $@

clean:
 rm -rf $(BINS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам дали так называемый diff файл или patch файл. В общем случае его нужно сохранить в файл (имя произвольное, расширение можно diff или patch). Дальше нужно скопировать этот файл в каталог с исходниками (очень часто это каталог src или там, где Makefile). Теперь запускаем утилиту patch

```
patch --dry-run -i <имя файла патча>
```

dry-run не применяет патч, а делает "пробу". Если будет ругаться, что пути не совпадают, то нужно либо перенести патч файл, либо воспользоваться параметром `-p`, которому передать число, что бы оно пути подкорректировало. Если все ок, то убираем dry-run и оно все "пропатчит".

Но если присмотрется к самому файлу, то они предлагают сделать изменения в одной строке в несколько символов.

Нужно открыть файл Makefile и в районе 17 строки сделать такую замену

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $^
```

на

```
$(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения! Я изменил мейк файл, ошибка осталась. Видимо где-то коллизия  с библиотеками. Создал файл с расширением patch, запустил - вот что вышло: Checking file Makefile Hunk #1 failed at 17 1 out of 1 Hunk failed.  И кстати, сделал так - `gcc -Wall (мои сырцы) -o (выходные) 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gdk gtk+-2.0 glib-2.0 gobject-2.0 gstreamer-1.0'`, та же печаль.

Comment: я посмотрел внимательно - код использует gstreamer очень старой версии, которая уже не совместима по апи.

Comment: Получается, что 1.0  и выше уже не применима без переписывания кода?

Comment: Нашел форкнутыйй пример, тут вроде бы есть поддержка версии выше https://github.com/jamesbond3142/gst-player/blob/james/gst-backend.c Пошло компилится, но на некоторые референсы начал ругаться.

Comment: В общем я поправил исходники, проект удачно скомпилировался, но линковку не прошел, ссылаясь на отсутствие библиотек. Я насильно впихнул в файл makefile пути: `LDFLAGS := -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0` И все равно та же проблема.